# Captions disappear when length changed manually in Premiere timeline

Tags: premiere, subtitles, closed-captioning, .srt

I am editing a video in Premiere that has srt subtitles/captions as a distinct captions layer. At the beginning, I was able to change the position of individual captions manually using the handles within the srt layer. For example, the caption below can be moved or scaled within the timeline.

[image: Captions layer (purple) where highlighted caption can be moved or have its length changed]

However, sometimes a timeline layer will eventually change so that extending or reducing the length of the caption causes the individual caption to immediately disappear from the srt layer. The caption below will disappear from the timeline if altered using its handles. It will remain visible in the caption bin's srt file, but has no thumbnail.

[image: highlighted caption that disappears if edited manually][image: caption bin with caption that disappeared in timeline - stays in bin w/o thumbnail]

In both cases, the captions layer have been cut and edited, and individual captions can have their length and position altered in the captions bin.

The adobe forums and documentation have been pretty useless regarding their captioning features. Any advice on how to get captions to play nice would be very helpful.